# Header text style in NavigatioPage Xamarin Form UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I'm creating an application in Xamarin forms for UWP platform

Is it possible to make wrap bartext in NavigationPage when its too long?. 
[image]

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any problem?

Comment: I had lots of problems with customization xamarin so i abandoned this solution and created separated UWP app. I couldnt find truncation and wrap property for Header but thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's OK, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make wrap bartext in NavigationPage when its too long?

`NavigationPage` doesn't really need markup to work, a `NavigationPage` will most likely host a number of different `ContentPage`s.

So I can only guess what you've done in your `ContentPage`. If you're defining the `Title` of `ContentPage`, then your text should always be capitalized, and it will always wrap the word automatically.

Base on your posted image, and a lot of tests, I assume that you're using `Label` to host the test here. If so, it is easy to make it wrap, you can refer to [Truncation and Wrapping](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label/#Truncation_and_Wrapping). In a word, you can for example just set the [LineBreakMode property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/) to `WordWrap`.

If you're not using Label to host the `Text` here, please update your question and post the code for your layout, so can we keep working on this case.